# Groovy while loop not executed correctly

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I've following simple while loop code in groovy -

```
def count = 1
while(count <= 5) {
    println "$count"
    sleep(5000)
    println "Sleeping for 5 seconds"
    count++
}
```

Which indicates that loop is executed only twice still second time `Sleeping for 5 seconds` is not run. Actually with this code, while block is expected to be executed 5 times. Can someone help to understand why such a weird behaviour?

When this code is run, output is following -

```
1
Sleeping for 5 seconds
2
```

Comment: looks like you are facing some timeout issue with your console... it executes just fine: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5103210607935488

Comment: @injecteer, it worked with what you provided.  I was trying with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php and got above result. I'm also facing some other issue with same script on Jenkins, will raise some other question.

Comment: Why should an public online eval service allow people from the internet to burn away their resources? This is not a groovy problem - if this is a problem with jenkins then i suggest tagging just as that.

Comment: yeah, obviously a sandobx time limitations of your console

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
~ $ cat doit.groovy 
def count = 1
while(count <= 5) {
    println "$count"
    sleep(5000)
    println "Sleeping for 5 seconds"
    count++
}
~ $ groovy doit
1
Sleeping for 5 seconds
2
Sleeping for 5 seconds
3
Sleeping for 5 seconds
4
Sleeping for 5 seconds
5
Sleeping for 5 seconds
```

Comment: Yes, it worked but I was trying with tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php and got above unexpected result. I'm also facing some other issue with same script on Jenkins, will raise some other question

Comment: "it worked but I was trying with tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php" - That isn't obvious from your question, and is a relevant detail.