# Unexpected behaviour with Groovy while loop execution in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I created simple Jenkins pipeline job with only having 'Pipeline script' in it -

```
node {
    stage('test') {
        def count = 1
       while(count <= 5) {
           echo "Count is $count"
        echo "Sleeping for 5 seconds..."
        sleep(5000)
        count++
       }
    }
}
```

When ran the job, I get following result -

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestFile
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] echo
Count is 1
[Pipeline] echo
Sleepig for 5 seconds...
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 1 hr 23 min
```

After first while block execution, it sleeps saying `Sleeping for 1 hr 23 min`. How does this abrupt sleep come?

However same groovy script runs fine outside of Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the below:-

```
echo "Sleeping for 5 seconds..."
sleep(5)
count++
```

As sleep is considering the value in second not in milliseconds, please follow the link for more [info](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep).

Comment: Thanks this worked! But it is strange for same sleep method working differently. Please see answers and comments of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395746/groovy-while-loop-not-executed-correctly/58402040#58402040